# JTextField, set caret position to end of input without highlighting whole string

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, netbeans-7, caret

I'm really baffled because I thought I solved this problem. I have a custom JDialog where the user inputs an equation, and there are buttons to add special characters to the input at the location of the cursor. Here's the function I have to add a special character:

```
private void addSymbol(String symbol) {

    int pos = input.getCaretPosition();
    String currInput = input.getText();
    input.setText(currInput.subSequence(0, pos) + symbol
            + currInput.subSequence(pos, currInput.length()));
    input.requestFocus();
    input.setCaretPosition(pos+1);

}
```

I'm working in Netbeans, and yesterday this function was working as expected. You press a button, the character is added at the cursor position, and the cursor is moved to right after the new character, allowing you to continue typing without interruption, even if the added character is at the end of the string. Today, I was trying to copy my code into a different type of project, so I renamed the working project a couple of times before giving up and putting the old name back.

Now when I try to add a special character at the end of the input, the entire input string is highlighted, so it's really easy to type something, add a character, then keep typing and accidentally overwrite everything you just input. It works fine when you add a character in the middle of the string. I tried doing a clean build, restarting Netbeans, and I removed various pieces of this function to make sure the version I was seeing was actually the one being called (I had an incident with this not being the case before, so now I'm paranoid). Does anyone know what could be going on or how to set the cursor at the end of the string without highlighting it?

EDIT: Here's test code

GetExpressionDialog.java

```
package bepe;

public class GetExpressionDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    /** Creates new form GetExpressionDialog */
    public GetExpressionDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        input = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        andButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        orButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        stileButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        messageLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        submitButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        notButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        impliesButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowClosing(evt);
            }
        });

        andButton.setText("∧");
        andButton.setToolTipText("You can also type \"&\"");
        andButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                andButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        orButton.setText("∨");
        orButton.setToolTipText("You can also type \"|\"");
        orButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                orButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        stileButton.setText("⊢");
        stileButton.setToolTipText("You can also type \"|-\"");
        stileButton.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        stileButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                stileButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        messageLabel.setText("Enter the sequent you would like to prove:");

        submitButton.setText("Submit");
        submitButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                submitButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        notButton.setText("¬");
        notButton.setToolTipText("You can also type \"!\"");
        notButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                notButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        impliesButton.setText("→");
        impliesButton.setToolTipText("You can also type \"->\"");
        impliesButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                impliesButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(20, 20, 20)
                        .add(messageLabel))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(20, 20, 20)
                        .add(input, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 482, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .add(stileButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(notButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(andButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(orButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(impliesButton, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, 200, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .add(submitButton)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(messageLabel)
                .add(8, 8, 8)
                .add(input, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(stileButton)
                    .add(notButton)
                    .add(andButton)
                    .add(orButton)
                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(impliesButton)
                        .add(submitButton)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void stileButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        addSymbol("⊢");

    }                                           

    private void andButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        addSymbol("∧");

    }                                         

    private void orButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        addSymbol("∨");

    }                                        

    private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

        dispose();

    }                                            

    private void notButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        addSymbol("¬");

    }                                         

    private void impliesButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        addSymbol("→");

    }                                             

    private void formWindowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                   

        input.setText("");

    }                                  

    private void addSymbol(String symbol) {

        int pos = input.getCaretPosition();
        String currInput = input.getText();
        input.setText(currInput.subSequence(0, pos) + symbol
                + currInput.subSequence(pos, currInput.length()));
        input.requestFocus();
        input.setCaretPosition(pos+1);

    }

    public String getText() {
        return input.getText();
    }

    public javax.swing.JLabel getMessage() {
        return messageLabel;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GetExpressionDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GetExpressionDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GetExpressionDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GetExpressionDialog.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the dialog */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                GetExpressionDialog dialog = new GetExpressionDialog(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
                dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton andButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton impliesButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField input;
    private javax.swing.JLabel messageLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton notButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton orButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton stileButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton submitButton;
    // End of variables declaration
```

test.java

```
package bepe;

public class test {

    public test(){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GetExpressionDialog dialog = new GetExpressionDialog(null, true);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        String input = dialog.getText();
        if (input.isEmpty()) return;

    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: agreed, really important to see SSCCE if you playing with JDialog, everything another should be shots to the dark

Comment: Why do you call requestFocus()? May be it's better to make the buttons not focusable?

Comment: I called requestFocus() so you can continue typing without having to click on the text field again. If making the buttons not focusable has the same effect, I can try that, but I'm not sure that that's the reason it's happening

Comment: please what's `Expression` e.g. `addSymbol(Expression.NOT);`

Comment: Oh for the love of Pete, making the buttons not focusable fixed the problem. Thanks. I would still like to know why what I had isn't working, there's gotta be a logical reason.
@mKorbel - I forgot to take those out at first, the actual string is in the question now

Comment: I think you have somewhere focus listener to highlight all the text field selection. So when the field looses focus and get it back the content becomes selected.

Comment: @StanislavL welcome to the >10k users

Comment: @kleopatra I'm sorry, what java naming conventions am I not using? The only place I see where I didn't follow the convention is the test class I made in literally 30 seconds before realizing it wasn't even necessary. If you're going to make bitchy unhelpful comments, at least be correct.

Comment: bitchy or not, until now it is _correct_ (once is once too often :)

Comment: Protip : Do not use NetBeans. Use Eclipse -.-

Answer (score 3):

Your code for inserting the special character is not the most effiecient. You don't need to replace the entire text. Just use:

```
textField.replaceSelection( symbol );
```

Also, next time post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. There is no need to post 300 lines of code for a simple focus problem. Also, posting code with non JDK classes doesn't help us run the code either.